# Problem using inequality and ratios

Tags: inequality

Two integers are in the ratio 5:8. If their sum is less than 100, what is the greatest possible value of the small integer.

Comment: I don't know if that's a Mathematica question. The integers are x=5n and y=8n with n integer. Their sum is hence 13n. So the maximal n is 7, and hence the answer is 35.

Comment: thx for the help!!